# How to describe the faces of the linear image of a box?

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

Given a box $B = [0, a_1] \times … \times [0, a_n]$ in the “non-negative orthant” of $\mathbb{R}^n$, we can define a face of $B$ to be the set of all points we get by fixing one of the interval’s endpoints. For example, for $B = [0, 3] \times [0, 2]$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$, one of the faces would be $\{3\} \times [0,2]$ (so in the 2D case, a "face" is just a side).

My question is, given a linear map from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$, is there some way I can describe the “faces” of the image of the box $TB$? It seems like we can’t really use intervals so simply anymore, since $T$ could stretch vectors in different directions. For example, the image of $[0,3] \times [0,2]$ could be a parallelogram.

I am asking this because it seems like a natural question. For example, if we stretch a cube in $\mathbb{R}^3$ into a parallelepiped, we might want to be able to describe its faces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the box $B = [0, a_1] \times \cdots \times [0, a_n]$ for some real numbers $a_k \geq 0.$ Observe that a $0$-dimensional face (a point) of $B$ can be described as the $n$-fold Cartesian product $\{i_1\} \times \cdots \times \{i_n\},$ where we have that $i_k \in \{0, a_k\}$ for each integer $1 \leq k \leq n.$ Likewise, in order to form an $i$-dimensional face $F$ ($1 \leq i \leq n$), we must first choose $n - i$ of the endpoints $i_k \in \{0, a_k\}$ -- say $i_k = 0$ for all integers $1 \leq k \leq n - i;$ then, $F$ can be described as the $n$-fold Cartesian product $\{i_1\} \times \cdots \times \{i_{n - i}\} \times [0, a_{n - i + 1}] \times \cdots \times [0, a_n].$

Consider a linear operator $T : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n,$ where we view $\mathbb R^n$ as an $\mathbb R$-vector space by identifying the point $P = (x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n)$ with the ray $\mathbf v = \langle x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n \rangle$ from the origin to $P.$ Consequently, an $i$-dimensional face $F$ ($1 \leq i \leq n$) is identified with the set of vectors $\mathbf v = \langle x_1, \dots, x_n \rangle$ such that $P = (x_1, \dots, x_n)$ is contained in $F.$ We can the describe the faces of the image $T(B)$ of the box $B$ under $T$ as the collection of vectors $T(\mathbf v)$ such that $\mathbf v$ is a vector corresponding to a point $P$ in $F.$ Unfortunately, I do not think there is a more convenient way of viewing the faces of $T(B)$ than this. Luckily, if you wish to compute $T(B),$ it suffices to compute the codimension $1$ (i.e., $(n - 1)$-dimensional) faces, as these determine the lower dimension faces.

**Example.** Consider the box $B = [0, 1] \times [0, 1]$ in $\mathbb R^2.$ We will find the image of $B$ under the linear operator $T(x, y) = \langle 2x - y, x + 2y \rangle.$ Like usual, we will identify $u = u(x, y) = 2x - y$ and $v = v(x, y) = x + 2y.$ Considering that linear operators map parallelograms to parallelograms, it suffices to find the image of the edges (1.) $[0, 1] \times \{0\},$ (2.) $\{1\} \times [0, 1],$ (3.) $[0, 1] \times \{1\},$ and (4.) $\{0\} \times [0, 1].$

(1.) We have that $T(x, 0) = \langle 2x, x \rangle$ for $0 \leq x \leq 1,$ hence this edge is mapped to the line $v = \frac u 2$ for $0 \leq u \leq 2.$

(2.) We have that $T(1, y) = \langle 2 - y, 1 + 2y \rangle$ for $0 \leq y \leq 1,$ hence this edge is mapped to the line $v = 5 - 2u$ for $1 \leq u \leq 2.$

(3.) We have that $T(x, 1) = \langle 2x - 1, x + 2 \rangle$ for $0 \leq x \leq 1,$ hence this edge is mapped to the line $v = \frac{u + 5} 2$ for $-1 \leq u \leq 1.$

(4.) We have that $T(0, y) = \langle -y, 2y \rangle$ for $0 \leq y \leq 1,$ hence this edge is mapped to the line $v = -2u$ for $-1 \leq u \leq 0.$

Ultimately, the linear operator maps $B$ to the [parallelogram cut out by these four lines](https://www.geogebra.org/calculator/uqhf93gr) in the $uv$-plane.

**Example.** Consider the box $B = [0, 1] \times [0, 1] \times [0, 1]$ in $\mathbb R^3.$ We will find the image of $B$ under the linear operator $T(x, y, z) = \langle x + y, x + z, y + z \rangle.$ Once again, we will identify $u = u(x, y, z) = x + y,$ $v = v(x, y, z) = x + z,$ and $w = w(x, y, z) = y + z.$ Like we mentioned above, it suffices to compute $T(F_1), \dots, T(F_6),$ where the $F_i$ ($1 \leq i \leq 6$) are the $2$-dimensional faces of $B.$

(1.) We have that $T(x, y, 0) = \langle x + y, x, y \rangle$ for $0 \leq x, y \leq 1,$ hence $T(F_1)$ is mapped to the portion of the plane $u = v + w$ for $0 \leq v, w \leq 1.$

(2.) We have that $T(x, y, 1) = \langle x + y, x + 1, y + 1 \rangle$ for $0 \leq x, y \leq 1,$ hence $T(F_2)$ is mapped to the portion of the plane $u = v + w - 2$ for $1 \leq v, w \leq 2.$

(3.) We have that $T(x, 0, z) = \langle x, x + z, z \rangle$ for $0 \leq x, z \leq 1,$ hence $T(F_3)$ is mapped to the portion of the plane $v = u + w$ for $0 \leq u, w \leq 1.$

(4.) We have that $T(x, 1, z) = \langle x + 1, x + z, z + 1 \rangle$ for $0 \leq x, z \leq 1,$ hence $T(F_4)$ is mapped to the portion of the plane $v = u + w - 2$ for $1 \leq u, w \leq 2.$

(5.) We have that $T(0, y, z) = \langle y, z, y + z \rangle$ for $0 \leq y, z \leq 1,$ hence $T(F_5)$ is mapped to the portion of the plane $w = u + v$ for $0 \leq u, v \leq 1.$

(6.) We have that $T(1, y, z) = \langle y + 1, z + 1, y + z \rangle$ for $0 \leq y, z \leq 1,$ hence $T(F_6)$ is mapped to the portion of the plane $w = u + v - 2$ for $1 \leq u, v \leq 2.$

Ultimately, the linear operator maps $B$ to the [rhombic prism cut out by these six planes](https://www.geogebra.org/3d/r3rpfcpx) in $\mathbb R^3.$